# Element disappeared while toggle v-if and v-else with different templates in v-menu activator

Tags: vuetify.js

While toggling two different activator templates in v-menu

```
<v-menu offset-y>
  <template v-if="mini" v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-list-item  v-on="on">
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>Jane Smith</v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle>Logged In</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </template>
  <template v-else v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn v-on="on">
      Login
    </v-btn>
  </template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item>Position 1</v-list-item>
    <v-list-item>Position 2</v-list-item>
    <v-list-item>Position 3</v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

we have each of them are disappeared after switching back.

All works only if there is an identical root element in each template.

This is for Vuetify 2.0.3

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aeyeNv
Try 'Click Me' button to toggle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to why vuetify doesn't handle a different kind of child element, I haven't had a look into the source.

However if you want it to work with different root elements, you can use the `mini` variable as the key for the parent element (`v-menu`) which will re-create the component, so it won't be an issue

```html
<v-menu offset-y :key='mini'>
  ...
</v-menu>
```

This is a bit of a hack, but it works and sometimes that's enough...